# Lines from div follows another specific div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help of making lines follows another specific div.
I have five circle1, circle2, circle3, circle4, circle5 and four lines, and the four lines follows the div circle5, something like this:
[image: Lines]

This is how the code look like

```
<div class="circle1"></div>
<svg><line id="line" x1="20" y1="100" x2="100" y2="100" stroke-width="2" stroke="black"></line></svg>

<div class="circle2"></div>
<svg><line id="line" x1="20" y1="100" x2="100" y2="100" stroke-width="2" stroke="black"></line></svg>

<div class="circle3"></div>
<svg><line id="line" x1="20" y1="100" x2="100" y2="100" stroke-width="2" stroke="black"></line></svg>

<div class="circle4"></div>
<svg><line id="line" x1="20" y1="100" x2="100" y2="100" stroke-width="2" stroke="black"></line></svg>

<div class="circle5"></div>
```

How do I achieve this with css or JS?

Comment: please share your complete analysis, regarding whats your approach, what you have achieved and where you are stuck.

Comment: Analysis of what?
I think the question is clear enough.
I want to css code that will make the lines rotate and follow the circle5 in html, please see the image in the question.

Comment: Please don’t just vaguely mention your issues here, try to show us what you tried till now. Please go read How to Ask and Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example in stackoverflow.

Comment: There is nothing vaguely. I have basic HTML, and I want someone to help with the CSS part, that's all.
I hope to get an answer to my question from you instead of comments.

Comment: SO is not a code making site. We help you improve/debug your OWN code. We will not make code for you. Especially when it's something so complex. There are freelancing sites for this. Just to help you out a bit, there's a plugin called `jsplumb` that does what you are looking for

Comment: I agree with you Mihai, thanks for your contribution, Vikran has answered it and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the above design using CSS `pseudo elements` along with some absolute positioning. Here is an rough example on how it can be achieved using CSS.

```css
.circle {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle:after {
content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-30deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
  <div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, could you possibly edit your answer and add two  `<div class="circle2"></div>` that connect each other through the line?

Comment: I want it to follow the second div no matter what the distance and the position will be, because the second div is is flexible.

Comment: I don't think it will be possible using CSS alone. You might need to add some custom js to achieve that.